# Can We Insert the Data into Cassandra Database using INSERT Query

Tags: nosql, cassandra, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I am working with wso2dss And using Cassandra database 
as per Wso2dss they showed update example .while i am using INSERT query its throwing errors
My query is like

```
 <query id="Insertinto" useConfig="CassandraDS">
     <sql>INSERT INTO StudentID('First Name','Last Name','Subjects','Class')  VALUES(?,?,?,?)</sql>
     <param name="First Name" ordinal="1" sqlType="STRING"/>
     <param name="Last Name" ordinal="2" sqlType="STRING"/>
     <param name="Subjects" ordinal="3" sqlType="STRING"/>
     <param name="Class" ordinal="4" sqlType="STRING"/>
  </query>
```

But i am getting error like below

```
[2013-06-25 11:38:38,060] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBDeployer} -  The CassandraStudentsSample.dbs service, which is not valid, caused {1}
DS Fault Message: Invalid query param name: 'first name', must be an NCName.
```

Comment: Does it work if you have no spaces in your param names, so 'First Name' becomes 'FirstName' and similarly for 'Last Name'?

Comment: i tried like that also even though its not working..

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the where clause you have to make sure you have indexed your Column Family when creating the Column Family or else you cannot use the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

The given error is thrown because of 'First Name' and 'Last Name' has spaces. Remove them and invoke. Are you getting the same error after removing them?

Comment: done as per your guidance even though throwing errorNested Exception:-
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Expected key 'KEY' to be present in WHERE clause for 'StudentID'

Comment: If you are using the where clause you have to make sure you have indexed your Column Family when creating the Column Family or else you cannot use the where clause.